# How To Implement Scroll Listener In Vaadin 7 Tables

Tags: vaadin

In Vaadin, when you scroll down or up in tables (**com.vaadin.ui.Table**) there is no event that will be fired to tell you that user is now scrolling.

#### Why would we need scroll event in table?

Let's first take a look at this example of Vaadin ([Dashboard Demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!/transactions)) after you open the link just click sign in, and you'll be automatically redirected to the transactions page, this page shows a table of financial transactions, these transactions will show a batch after another while you are scrolling, what actually happened is that the data was loaded on UI initiation (all the transactions).

Now, let's assume that we have thousands or say millions of transactions. Is it logic to load them all together when the UI is initiated? isn't it of wisdom to load them bit by bit to prevent slowing down the UI while it waits for all transactions to load?.

The best solution to this problem is to get the first (say 100 transactions) then get more transactions while scrolling down, but this solution have only one *problem*, that is Vaadin does not support **Scroll Event Handling** in **com.vaadin.ui.Table !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vaadin Table's Scrolling Event

The [Dashboard Demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/) (GitHub [repo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo)) project actually depends on Vaadin tables as you see in the code in [this](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L53) file in line **53**, what we are going to do is to extend **com.vaadin.ui.Table** and implement our own behavior that will support scrolling Vaadin tables from now on.

First of all, let's create new simple interface **ScrollingTableScrollListener** this interface will be responsible for implementing scroll events and its code will look like this:

```
package com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.scrolling;

public interface ScrollingTableScrollListener {
     public void doTableScroll();
}
```

This interface should be implemented whenever you have a **table** in your **view** and you want to add a **scroll** event handler for it. But wait a minute this is not applicable to any kind of tables, this is only applicable to our own table.

Now, let's create our table, our table's name is  (`ScrollingTable`) and it extends (`com.vaadin.ui.Table`) this class code is:

```
package com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.scrolling;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.vaadin.ui.Table;

public class ScrollingTable extends Table {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5007124121625961567L;
    List listeners = new ArrayList();

    private void fireSrollEvent() {
        for (ScrollingTableScrollListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.doTableScroll();
        }
    }

    public void addScrollListener(ScrollingTableScrollListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeVariables(Object source, Map variables) {
        super.changeVariables(source, variables);
        fireSrollEvent();
    }
}
```

Actually, this table is the same as Vaadin's one, but it has the following differences:

1. It overrides the method changeVariables() of the super class (Vaadin Table : **com.vaadin.ui.Table**), actually here lays our core business that will initiate the Scrolling Behavior. What we did here is that we invoked the `changeVariables()` of the super class and then we invoked the `fireSrollEvent()` method.
2. Another difference is that it has two more members:

   1. **public void addScrollListener(ScrollingTableScrollListener listener)** this method will take care of adding new listeners to table's scrolling event.
   2. **private void fireSrollEvent()** this method is the one that will be invoked by `changeVariables()` method and will invoke the method `doTableScroll()` on every registered listener that this table has added by invoking the method `addScrollListener().`

Now to make use of the new stuff that we have added, we will change the original code of the aforementioned Dashboard demo (specifically the file [TransactionsView.java](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L53)). In this file there are only few lines to add and modify.

First, we will modify the [line 49](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L49) by adding new interface that this class will implement, which is our new interface (ScrollingTableScrollListener) and implement its single method by adding the following lines in the end of this class:

```
@Override
public void doTableScroll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Notification.show("You are scrolling!\nYou can add your own behavior here!");
}
```

Then, we will change both lines [53](https://github.com/ashajjar/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L53) and [66](https://github.com/ashajjar/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L66) to use the new inherited class (ScrollingTable) rather than the super class (Table):

```
//Line 53 in the original class
Table t;
//Line 55 in our class
ScrollingTable t;
....
....
....
//line 66 in the original class
t = new Table() {
//line 68 in our class
t = new ScrollingTable() {
```

Finally, we should add the listener to our ScrollingTable's scrolls :) , this is done by invoking the method addScrollListener on the table (t) after defining the table ([line 89](https://github.com/ashajjar/dashboard-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/TransactionsView.java#L89) of our new class):

```
t.addScrollListener(this);
```

this line means that this class (TransactionView) is listening on the ScrollingTable (t) scroll event, and it will invoke the method doTableScroll whenever the user scrolls down/up the ScrollingTable (t).

Here you go, you have now a table that will tell you whenever the user is scrolling, your task now is to do what you want when the table fires scrolling event and put your stuff between the curly brackets `{}` of the method that we defined in the first step:

```
@Override
public void doTableScroll() {
      // Put your own code here ...
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ashajjar/dashboard-demo/) of the new Dashboard on GitHub.

The answer on my [blog](http://ashajjar85.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/how-to-implement-scroll-listener-in-vaadin-7-tables/)

Comment: I modified the answer :)

Comment: As someone else also pointed out in the blog comments, your implementation fires `doTableScroll` whenever any event on the table occurs. I guess you need to filter the messages and only fire `doTableScroll` whenever `variables` contains scrolling.

Comment: I have implemted your coud but the scroll event is not being fired! The only event that is being fired is when I click on a item of the table o when the table is loaded... what can I check?

Comment: @AhmadHajjar What method would you override if one is subclassing a Grid instead of table like --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380115/how-to-recalculate-column-widths-on-scroll-downnot-programmatic-to-a-previousl

Answer (score 2):

According to your question you are looking for lazy loading.

If you connect your table with a container which supports lazy loading your items are loaded from it's data source lazily. This means when you scroll and get out of the buffered items the table "asks" the container for more items. The container then loads more items from it's data source.

For example the [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-jpacontainer) from Vaadin supports that feature. This container connects to a data source using JPA. More information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.html).

Comment: I like this but I am talking here about scrolling event :)

Comment: @X-Ware I know you are talking about scroll listener but according to [...]
The best solution to this problem is to get the first (say 100 transactions) then get more transactions while scrolling down [...]
 I want to mention that there is also a lazy loading feature.

Comment: @nexus and this "feature" is broken in, for instance, SQLContainer, so it makes sense that the user wants to implement it himself...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, event fires on EVERY action with table (such as row select, etc.). More appropricate solution is additional checking variable changing in table state.

Here example:

```
public class ScrollingTable extends Table {

// ...

@Override
public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
    super.changeVariables(source, variables);
    handleScrollEvent(variables);
}

private void handleScrollEvent(Map<String, Object> variables) {
    if (variables.containsKey("firstvisible")) {
        for (TableScrollListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.doTableScroll();
        }
    }
}
```